# Formula to mimic pivot table behavior

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to do something that's quite easy to do with a pivot table, but with one single formula, which is to array group all the categories in the "category column" with their respective sums and then return the category which has the maximum value.

In google sheets I could use a query formula with a group by, but in Excel, I'm not sure if it's possible.

```
Category            value
A                   20
B                   7
A                   30
B                   12
A                   3
B                   5
```

The formula should return "A", since the sum of all "A"=53 and "B" is only 22

Note: In my spreadsheet, I might have as many as thousands of categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with INDEX/AGGREGATE as an array formula:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A$2:$A$7)/(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,$A$2:$A$7)=MAX(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,$A$2:$A$7))),1))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: is there a way to make the $A$2:$A$7 part dynamic? Since I don't know how many rows I'm going to have.

Comment: Yes replace all the `$A$2:$A$7` with `$A$2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A))`